# Love and Vengeance

Tags: riddle

I'm in love, with one I ne'er could pair.
But call me not a silly goose, for they're in me.

I'm all for vendettas, but ne'er did kill a soul.
Yet for taking revenge you will need my help.

My next of kin is twice the man I am,
Yet named more for the one I followed in.

You have already missed me twice,
Now speak and tell me truly: who am I?

Comment: @JonMarkPerry Please don't make pointless edits.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You are

> the letter V.

I'm in love, with one I ne'er could pair.

> "lo**v**e"

But call me not a silly goose, for they're in me.

> Geese fly in a V pattern.

I'm all for vendettas, but ne'er did kill a soul.

> a reference to the graphic novel and movie "V for Vendetta"

Yet for taking revenge you will need my help.

> re**v**enge

My next of kin is twice the man I am,

> "w" looks like two "v"s...

Yet named more for the one I followed in.

> ...but is called "double-U".

You have already missed me twice,

> "ne'er" was said twice, and the V was omitted.

Now speak and tell me truly: who am I?

> The letter **V**!

Comment: Wow, Deuso'i sure is fast.